# iTunes Connect Testflght Beta Testing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

Can we give multiple versions which we are going to release subsequently of the same application for the testers to test it in iTunes Connect.

As anyone effectively using this iTunes Connect Tesflight beta Testing?

Can you please direct me to any good tutorial on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial,and it sounds pretty good:
[Testflight Beta Testing](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

Answer (score 1):

Video Tutorial to learn the beta testing 
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/TestFlight-v09-iTC-Export-sw.mov

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upload different builds of same application to `iTune connect` for that you have to ensure that build numbers should be different otherwise you cant upload your build to `iTune connect`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With this can we test application only in iOS 8. What if we have to test it in iOS 6 and iOS 7?

Comment: Actually you can upload iOS 7 or iOS 6 applications to iTunes connect . But the the test flight beta applications which we are using for downloading your app for testing requires minimum iOS 8. So you can test your iOS 7 application(deployment target: iOS 7) also in iOS 8 devices. You can also use other options like hockey app  http://hockeyapp.net/apps/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have multiple versions of your app available for TestFlight. As far as I know you can only have two versions available. Your current version and the following version. After you've created a new version of your current app the 'new version' button disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multiple versions of your app each version will be available to the testers for a period of 30 days.